# Why does Gradle build my project twice

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

First click to rebuild the Android app project and then click to run the app. I notice that the app is built twice.

The event log shows:

```
01:17:57 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
01:18:06 Gradle build finished in 8s 559ms
01:18:12 Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
01:18:20 Gradle build finished in 8s 407ms
```

I haven't changed any code before clicking `Run`, so why does Gradle have to build the project AGAIN instead of deploying the app directly?

Comment: The first step isn't doing `app:assembleDebug` and the first one cleans the entire project, not only the app module

Comment: In a more normal build (not a `clean` one), if you look at the details in the Gradle Console, you will see that many of the sub-tasks inside of those are skipped, marked as "UP-TO-DATE". Android Studio has no idea what sorts of things you may be doing in your Gradle build file that might need to be performed again when you run the app. It just executes the task to build the app, relying on existing change-detection logic to try to minimize the build time.